# I can't start mysql8.0 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I install mysql8.0, its fine.
but i want change Data Directory to a New Location.
It's follow this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-20-04

and follow step4，I can't restart Mysql

Now it’s time to start MySQL. If you do, however, you’ll run into another error. Instead of an AppArmor issue, this error is caused by mysql-systemd-start, a script that supports managing MySQL through systemd. You can inspect this script with the following command:

```
nano /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start
```

and it's out

```
verify_ready $1
    verify_database $1

    /lib/apparmor/profile-load usr.sbin.mysqld

    if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
            echo "MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Please install one."
            exit 1
    fi
```

So, how can fix this problem? and i don't want reinstall mysql, because i want change Data Directory to a New Location.
Thanks all

Comment: This is the story of my life every time I deal with MySQL vs MariaDB.  I know this isn't an answer to your problem but I just wanted to let you know.  MySQL provides support as it is a paid product.  MariaDB just works as it is built with each distro.  Is there a reason you aren't using the MariaDB that came with Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I use Mysql for Quant, MariaDb also can use on Ubuntu? and MariaDb work for Quant it's better than Mysql?

Comment: I will not say that MariaDB is better than MySQL.. that is a war I don't want to start.  Once upon a time, they were the same.  MySQL decided they wanted to charge and MariaDB became its own compatible fork of THE SAME CODE.  They have diverged a bit but remain compatible with each other.  Yes, built into Ubuntu's package system.  Compatible with Quant? I dunno.. probably.

Comment: Thanks for answer again, Also I dont' want war never, I just want fix this problem.And i check Mysql and MariaDb, as you said MariaDB is other option.
I'm a trader who just started teaching myself python, the first time I came into contact with mysql, and for algotrade, if mariadb can meet the basic trade needs, I believe this is a good choice. If you have the same big data usage scenario, maybe you can give me more suggestion, thanks

Comment: MariaDB is 100% pro.  It will scale as will Postgres.  Both come free with any Linux distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by leoce

01 modify /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld, change /var/lib/mysql to the custom path, then reload apparmor
02 disable apparmor for mysql

```
 sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld
03 disable apparmor completely

```
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```